# string_input_producer with num_epochs throws OutofRangeError

Tags: tensorflow

This code dequeues elements as expected:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
        queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([str(i) for i in range(10)])
        deq = queue.dequeue()

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        for i in range(3):
            print(sess.run([deq]))
```

However when I add `num_epochs` to string_input_producer it fails with `OutofRangeError`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
        queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([str(i) for i in range(10)], num_epochs=1)
        deq = queue.dequeue()

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        for i in range(3):
            print(sess.run([deq]))
```

I'm using tensorflow 0.9

Answer (score -1):

It needed `tf.initialize_all_variables().run()`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".